# MySQL Stored Procedure Runs Successfully but does not execute the mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE sdmLoggingSystem()
   BEGIN
   INSERT IGNORE INTO `databasename`.`tablename`
  (`stringval1`, `numericValue2`,`datetime`)
   values("AA",23,now());
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The above **MySQL Stored Procedure** runs successfully, but it does not insert the data into the table, But when I run the **mysql** query separately, it does insert into the table.
Is there anything wrong in the code that I cannot see?

Comment: is there autocommit mode for both cases?

Comment: no there is autocommit.

Comment: try without IGNORE and check any errors reported.

Comment: tried it, but it does not work with without IGNORE aswell

Comment: most likely you have different conditions inside stored procedure and have to see the error. Please check the following link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html